# mysql2 and close query in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql2

I am little new in JavaScript so i need to ask cause is different from Java..

I have an application and when starts i connected with mysql2 with this function:

connection.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "user",
    password: "passwd",
    database: "db"
});

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (err !== null) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

module.exports = {con};
```

I have export the 'con' so i can use it in some other files and works ok.
So the question is:

```
    let sql = "insert into reports(someValues) values (?)";
    try {
        e.con.execute(sql, [someValues], function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
}
```

when this query will be executed i want if is necessary to close the specific query.
Is it important to close this query or i can leave it as is because i execute multiply query's and i didn't find any way to close it...

Does anyone have any idea how to close the query after executed or i need to close the connection and reconnect after in the other query?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: i connect with const con = require("./connection");

Comment: MySQL server automatically closes idle connections with clients after some time -- you shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: I think you might be confusing queries with connections.

Comment: This is *not* a good approach for things like web applications. The connections will be shared and 2 queries happening at the same time will corrupt each other. I wrote a small article for people just starting off with mysql and node: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper class that keeps a handle on the client connection.

This class acts as an interface and encapsulates the `mysql2` logic. If you wanted to change `mysql2` out for another module, you would not have to change all the usages of this class across your codebase.

```js
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const { Connection } = require("mysql2/typings/mysql/lib/Connection");

class DatabaseConnection {
  /** @type {Connection} */ #client;

  constructor({ host, user, password, database }) {
    this.#client = mysql.createConnection({
      host,
      user,
      password,
      database,
    });
  }
  async query(sql) {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.#client.query(sql, (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        resolve(result, fields);
      });
    });
  }
  open() {
    this.#client.connect((err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (err !== null) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
  close() {
    this.#client.end((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err.message);
      }
      // close all connections
    });
  }
}

module.exports = { DatabaseConnection };
```

---

## Update

Here is an example of [Evert's suggestion](https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/) of `mysql2`.

### Dependencies

```json
"dependencies": {
  "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
  "mysql2": "^3.6.0"
}
```

### Sample SQL

Based on: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-table.php

```sql
--
-- Database: `company`
--

CREATE TABLE `agent` (
  `AGENT_CODE` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `AGENT_NAME` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WORKING_AREA` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMISSION` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PHONE_NO` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNTRY` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;

INSERT INTO `agent` (`AGENT_CODE`, `AGENT_NAME`, `WORKING_AREA`, `COMMISSION`, `PHONE_NO`, `COUNTRY`) VALUES
('A007', 'Ramasundar', 'Bangalore', 0.15, '077-25814763', 'India'),
('A003', 'Alex', 'London', 0.13, '075-12458969', 'United Kingdom'),
('A008', 'Alford', 'New York', 0.12, '044-25874365', 'United States'),
('A011', 'Ravi Kumar  ', 'Bangalore', 0.15, '077-45625874', 'India'),
('A010', 'Santakumar', 'Chennai', 0.14, '007-22388644', 'India'),
('A012', 'Lucida', 'San Jose', 0.12, '044-52981425', 'United States'),
('A005', 'Anderson', 'Brisban', 0.13, '045-21447739', 'Australia'),
('A001', 'Subbarao', 'Bangalore', 0.14, '077-12346674', 'India'),
('A002', 'Mukesh', 'Mumbai', 0.11, '029-12358964', 'India'),
('A006', 'McDen', 'London', 0.15, '078-22255588', 'United Kingdom'),
('A004', 'Ivan', 'Torento', 0.15, '008-22544166', 'Canada'),
('A009', 'Benjamin', 'Hampshair', 0.11, '008-22536178', 'United Kingdom');

ALTER TABLE `agent` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`AGENT_CODE`);
COMMIT;
```

### Environment

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_DATABASE=company
DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS=10
```

### Usage

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { createPool } from "mysql2/promise";

dotenv.config();

const parseInt2 = (value, defaultValue = 0, radix = 10) =>
  value && !isNaN(value) ? parseInt(value, radix) : defaultValue;

const {
  DB_DATABASE,
  DB_HOST,
  DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS,
  DB_PASSWORD,
  DB_PORT,
  DB_USER,
} = process.env;

const pool = createPool({
  host: DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt2(DB_PORT, 3306),
  user: DB_USER,
  password: DB_PASSWORD,
  database: DB_DATABASE,
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: parseInt2(DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS, 10),
  queueLimit: 0,
});

const transaction = async (pool, callback) => {
  const connection = await pool.getConnection();
  await connection.beginTransaction();
  try {
    await callback(connection);
    await connection.commit();
  } catch (err) {
    await connection.rollback();
    throw err; // Throw the error again so others can catch it.
  } finally {
    connection.release();
  }
};

const findAgentById = async (agentId) =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await transaction(pool, async (connection) => {
      const [results] = await connection.query(
        "SELECT * from `agent` WHERE `agent_code` = ?",
        [agentId]
      );
      if (results.length < 1) {
        reject("Agent with this id was not found");
      }
      resolve(results.pop());
    });
  });

const findAllAgents = async () =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await transaction(pool, async (connection) => {
      const [results] = await connection.query("SELECT * from `agent`");
      if (results.length < 1) {
        reject("No agents exist");
      }
      resolve(results);
    });
  });

const agent = await findAgentById("A003");

console.log("Agent", agent); // Agent: { AGENT_CODE: 'A003', ... }

const agents = await findAllAgents();

console.log("Total agents:", agents.length); // Total agents: 12

pool.end();
```

Here is an example of creating reusable query functions:

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { createPool } from "mysql2/promise";

dotenv.config();

const parseInt2 = (value, defaultValue = 0, radix = 10) =>
  value && !isNaN(value) ? parseInt(value, radix) : defaultValue;

const {
  DB_DATABASE,
  DB_HOST,
  DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS,
  DB_PASSWORD,
  DB_PORT,
  DB_USER,
} = process.env;

const pool = createPool({
  host: DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt2(DB_PORT, 3306),
  user: DB_USER,
  password: DB_PASSWORD,
  database: DB_DATABASE,
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: parseInt2(DB_MAX_CONNECTIONS, 10),
  queueLimit: 0,
});

const transaction = async (pool, callback) => {
  const connection = await pool.getConnection();
  await connection.beginTransaction();
  try {
    await callback(connection);
    await connection.commit();
  } catch (err) {
    await connection.rollback();
    throw err; // Throw the error again so others can catch it.
  } finally {
    connection.release();
  }
};

const extractTableNameFromQuery = (sql) => {
  const [, tableName] = sql.match(/(?<=from )`?(\w+)`?/);
  return tableName.toUpperCase();
};

const findBy = async (pool, sql, id) =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await transaction(pool, async (connection) => {
      const [results] = await connection.query(sql, [id]);
      if (results.length < 1) {
        reject(
          `${extractTableNameFromQuery(sql)} with this id=${id} was not found`
        );
      }
      resolve(results.pop());
    });
  });

const findAll = async (pool, sql) =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    await transaction(pool, async (connection) => {
      const [results] = await connection.query(sql);
      if (results.length < 1) {
        reject(`No ${extractTableNameFromQuery(sql)} records exist`);
      }
      resolve(results);
    });
  });

const findAgentById = async (agentId) =>
  findBy(pool, "SELECT * from `agent` WHERE `agent_code` = ?", [agentId]);

const findAllAgents = async () => findAll(pool, "SELECT * from `agent`");

try {
  const agent = await findAgentById("A003");
  console.log("Agent:", agent);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}

try {
  const agents = await findAllAgents();
  console.log("Total agents:", agents.length);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}

pool.end();
```

Comment: Many thanks to all! I will try them tomorrow and i will inform!!

Answer (score 0):

After you (or someone) call API on frontend and query will be executed.

So about you question you can close, or finish request on few ways.
First you can add this:

```
 (err, results) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    res.send(results);
  }
}
```

And when you send results on frontend query and API call is closed and finished.

Or you can use `res.end();` method.

I hope my answer will help you.